# Getting length as number?

Tags: lengths

I have probably formulated the question wrong, as I don't know the Tex internals - but this is what I mean; consider this example:

```
\newcommand{\myNum}{2}
\newlength{\myLength}
\setlength{\myLength}{\myNum cm}
```

Here, I'd consider `\myNum` to represent a 'numeric variable', and `\myLength` a Tex length (i.e. a number and a unit); and so I'd consider the above example a "conversion" from numeric to length "variable".

Is it possible to do the other way around? I.e. if `\myLength` is given to be 2 cm, is there a command that will "get"/"extract" the numeric value only? I'd imagine doing something like this (pseudocode):

```
\newcommand{\myNum}{\getlength{\myLength}}
```

... after which, `\myNum` would have value "2" ...

Does anything like this exist?

EDIT: I guess I need something similar to `\the` which is for counters ... ?!

Comment: `\the\myLength` gives you the dimension, I don't know how you'd extract just the number... If you wanted to do something like this, I expect the [`calc`](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf) package might be useful. Or possibly [this package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/fltpoint)

Comment: Thanks for noting that, @Seamus - I was not aware `\the` could be applied to lengths too (try searching for "latex \the", hehe :) ); `\theMyLength` indeed prints the length, but seemingly in `pt` units.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can remove the `pt` unit from the length using `\strip@pt` as shown below. I you want the number in cm you would have to convert it by yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getlength}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
% Or rounded back to `cm` (there will be some rounding errors!)
%\newcommand*{\getlength}[1]{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.035146\dimexpr#1\relax\relax}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test: \getlength{\textwidth}  % Result: 345

\end{document}
```

Another alternative which is more flexible and also allows you to store the resulting number in a macro is to use `pgfmath` (`pgf` package). It also allows you to easily convert the number to cm:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand*{\getlength}[2]{%
   \pgfmathsetmacro#1{#2}%  Result in `pt`
   % Or:
   %\pgfmathsetmacro#1{0.0351459804*#2}%  Result in `cm`
}

\begin{document}

\getlength{\myNum}{\textwidth}

Test: \myNum % Result: 345.0

\end{document}
```

There is also the `round( )` function for `pgfmath` which allows you to round the number, e.g. to two fractional digits. The trick is to multiple it with 100 before the rounding and divide it afterwards by 100.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand*{\getlength}[2]{%
   % Convert to `cm` and round to two fractional digits:
   \pgfmathsetmacro#1{round(3.51459804*#2)/100.0}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\textwidth}{2.123cm}
\getlength{\myNum}{\textwidth}

Test: \myNum% Gives 2.12

\setlength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\getlength{\myNum}{\textwidth}

Test: \myNum% Gives 2.0

\end{document}
```

The fractional part (like `.0`) can be avoided by using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`, but I don't think you need that.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for the fast response, @Martin Scharrer!

Comment: @sdaau: Minor note about the pgfmath round function: I wouldn't rely on the "multiply by 100, round, divide by 100" method.  I tried it recently and found that the accuracy was quite poor.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. An alternative would be to truncate the digits instead: `\def\twofracdigits#1.#2#3#4\relax{#1.#2#3}
\newcommand*{\getlength}[2]{%
   \pgfmathsetmacro#1{0.0351459804*#2}%
   \edef#1{\expandafter\twofracdigits#1\empty\empty\relax}%
}`. However the OP might not need this at all.

Comment: @sdaau: I've just tried the example where I got the inaccuracy and I can't reproduce it.  So I think I'd like to downgrade my warning a bit to just: "be careful".  However, I would recommend using the `\pgfmathprintnumber` command (see the pgf manual for more details) instead of the "multiply, round, divide" cycle.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, I didn't know about `\pgfmathprintnumber` myself.

Comment: @Martin: I think it's new in 2.10.

Comment: Cheers all - fantastic facts ITT :)

Comment: It might easier to use the CTAN package **lengthconvert** (which was released in 2013, 2 years after the accepted answer was posted)
https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/lengthconvert/lengthconvert.pdf

\Convert[unit=cm,number-only]{\myLength}}

Answer (score 14):

An alternative to Martin's approach is to use TeX's `\number` primitive, which will give you the underlying integer value in `sp`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\getlength[1]{\number#1}

\begin{document}

Test: \getlength{\textwidth}

\end{document}
```

(TeX does everything in integers, more or less, so lengths are actually stored in `sp`, which are tiny length units. Everything else is an integer multiple of a value in `sp`.)

Comment: Damn: I was 49 seconds slower.

Comment: @Bruno: Ah well :-)

Comment: Thanks for that @Bruno Le Floch & @Joseph Wright - great to know that primitive! (Also thanks for the note on internal storage in Tex)

Comment: +1 Just as a reference: 65536 sp = 1 pt

Comment: And if needed you can use the `fp` package to do calculations with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

One can use `xfp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlengthnumber}{O{pt}m}{%
  % #1 (optional, default pt), #2 = length
  \fpeval{(#2)/(1#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

\getlengthnumber{\textwidth}

\getlengthnumber[cm]{\textwidth}

\getlengthnumber[cm]{1in}

\getlengthnumber[sp]{1pt}

\end{document}
```

The big advantage over the `pgf` methods is that this is fully expandable.

[image]

Comment: Loading `xfp` is not necessary with LaTeX released October 2021 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to provide a simple solution with `pgf`

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\the\textwidth \\
\pgfmathparse{\textwidth}
\pgfmathresult \\
\end{document}
```

where `\the\textwidth` prints the length with units, while `\pgfmathparse` returns `\textwidth` without unit to `\pgfmathresult`

[image: length]

there are many more functions to choose from section *Mathematical Expressions* in [pgf](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) manual.

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage{xfp}` and then `\fpeval(\textwidth}`? By the way, your method is already covered in Martin Scharrer's answer.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, `\fpeval(\textwidth}` is also a nice solution. As for the second point, although we both used `pgf`, he used `\pgfmathsetmacro` and I used `\pgfmathparse`.