# Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a macro to extract the x and y coordinates from an arbitrary point, like `(3,4)`, or like `(A)`, or like `([xshift=-2pt] A.north west)`, where `A` is the name of a node.

I've seen the solution

```
 \newdimen\mydim
 \newcommand\getx[1]{
      \pgfextractx\mydim{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
 }
```

elsewhere on StackExchange, but this obviously won't work for all the cases described above. I need to be able to call `\getx{(3,4)}` and `\getx{(A)}` and `\getx{([xshift=-2pt] A.north west)}`, and for them all to work equally well, in this case putting the x-coordinate of the argument into the variable `\mydim`.

I'm kind of stunned how hard this seems to be! Surely I've missed something...

Comment: For a lot of these cases the `let` operation looks like a good fit. You can just go `let \p1 (3,4) in (\x1,0) -- (\x1,\y1)` then `\x1` and `\y1` will hold the `3` and `4` respectively. You can even do multiple points at once. All of this is within a `\path` the TikZ manual discusses it on page 150.

Comment: Roelof's answer is a good one for my case. FYI, the "let" command is discussed in section 14.15 of the TikZ manual for version 3.0.0, starting on page 161.

Comment: Related Question: [Compute the elevation of a coordinate in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173433/compute-the-elevation-of-a-coordinate-in-tikz).

Comment: Remark: answers below give the result in a dimen counter. To give the result in cm refer to [Getting length as number? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/getting-length-as-number/669398#669398).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}` to extract the `x`,`y` coordinate of the most recently used point into the dimension registers `\XCoord` and `{\YCoord}`.

To make the point the most recently used, I use `\path` macro just before extraction.  Here is an example where I define points, extract the x and y coordinates, and then label them via the extracted coordinates.  The point `C` is placed at the *x*-coordainte of `A` and the *y*-coordiante of `B`.

[image]

#### Notes:

- This has been updated to work properly when a `scale=` factor is applied to the `tikzpicture`. To see what the output is without tweaking for a scale factor uncomment the line

  ```
  %\let\ExtractCoordinate\ExtractCoordinateOld
  ```

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86897/recover-scaling-factor-in-tikz
\newcommand*\getscale[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfgettransformentries{\scaleA}{\scaleB}{\scaleC}{\scaleD}{\whatevs}{\whatevs}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{sqrt(abs(\scaleA*\scaleD-\scaleB*\scaleC))}%
    \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@XCoord
\newdimen\@YCoord
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{%
    \getscale{\@scalefactor}
    \path [transform canvas] (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\@XCoord}{\@YCoord}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\XCoord}{\@XCoord/\@scalefactor}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\YCoord}{\@YCoord/\@scalefactor}
}
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinateOld}[1]{%
    \path [transform canvas] (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}%
}%
%\let\ExtractCoordinate\ExtractCoordinateOld
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\LabelCurrentCoordinate}[2]{%
    \fill [#1] ($(\XCoord,\YCoord)$) circle (2pt) node [right] {#2}
}


\newdimen\XCoordA
\newdimen\YCoordA
\newdimen\XCoordB
\newdimen\YCoordB

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \coordinate (A) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (B) at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1cm] A.north west);

    \ExtractCoordinate{$(A)$};
    \LabelCurrentCoordinate{red}{A};
    \setlength\XCoordA{\XCoord}
    \setlength\YCoordA{\YCoord}

    \ExtractCoordinate{$(B)$};
    \LabelCurrentCoordinate{blue}{B};
    \setlength\XCoordB{\XCoord}
    \setlength\YCoordB{\YCoord}

    \ExtractCoordinate{$(\XCoordA,\YCoordB)$};
    \LabelCurrentCoordinate{magenta}{C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use different new dimensions for different points, both still end up the same size. Is it possible to save the value somehow?

Comment: @cfr: Not sure I understand. Can you post a new question with a MWE that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Nice! How to use it inside a `\foreach`?

Comment: @Sigur: Sorry, not sure how I missed this comment.  Can you elaborate as I am not understanding what the issue is in using this within a `\foreach`. As I just edited this question, now would be a good time to address that issue as well.

Comment: @PeterGrill, hi, Thanks. Ow, don't worry, forget my comment. Now I have a better knowledge and I'm able to use your tool within a loop. Regards.

Answer (score 44):

The answers from Peter, Jamie, and wh1t3 (the last one in the comments) are all fine.  I'm adding this as a "low level" version since this is often something that one wants to do as a part of a bigger thing, and then it can be useful to know how to do it at this lower level.

The TikZ command that scans a coordinate and figures out where it actually corresponds to is called `\tikz@scan@one@point`.  It sort-of takes two arguments.  The first is a macro, the second is the point to be scanned.  The "sort-of" is because the second argument isn't an argument, it's just the bare coordinate.  The coordinate is parsed until TikZ feels that it understands it enough to produce an honest x-y coordinate on the page, whereupon is called the macro with that x-y coordinate as its argument (specifically, it calls `\themacro{\pgfpoint{x-coord}{y-coord}}`.  By specifying the macro to be `\@firstofone` (or `\pgfutil@firstofone` if we want to be good PGFers) we can set `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` to be those coordinates.  If we want to save them, we could either pass a fancy saving macro or simply save the values of `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` afterwards.

Here's a simple example where we define a macro that takes three arguments, being the coordinate and two macros in which to save the x and y coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. node[auto] (A) {A} (3,3);
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
\fill[red,fill opacity=.5] (\ax,\ay) circle[radius=12pt];
\begin{scope}[rotate=45,xshift=3cm]
\draw (0,0) -- node[auto] (B) {B} (3,2);
\end{scope}
\gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
\fill[blue,fill opacity=.5] (\bx,\by) circle[radius=12pt];
\gettikzxy{([xshift=-2cm] A.north west)}{\cx}{\cy}
\fill[green] (\cx,\cy) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill ([xshift=-2cm] A.north west) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The last one is taken from your question but I changed the shift to `2cm` so that it would be more obvious.)

The result is:

[image: get TikZ coordinates]

Comment: I was very keen on using this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with `pgfplots`: I add this: `\begin{axis} ; \addplot[name path global=cfunc,blue,domain=0:3.1] {sin(deg(x))} ; \node[auto, name path global=D] (D) at (2,2) {D} ; \gettikzxy{(D)}{\ax}{\ay} ; \end{axis}` right before the `\end{tikzpicture}` in this snippet, and the failure is: "Package pgf Error: No shape named D is known." (neither are the other nodes from an `axis` environment known). Any possibility for that kind of use?

Comment: @sdaau My guess is that the `axis` environment saves up its drawing commands until the end, so the `D` node is not positioned until the `axis` environment is finished.  Within the `axis` environment then `\gettikzxy` is executed straight away and so before `D` is positioned.  If you shift the `\gettikzxy` after the `\end{axis}` then it seems to work.  Can you use it like that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LoopSpace - it makes sense; I'd guess it will work that way (unfortunately, I lost the original example leading to the comment). Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

This feels very wrong, but I'll do it anyway...

```
\newdimen{\tempx}
\newdimen{\tempy}
\newcommand\getxy[1]{
    \coordinate (tmp) at #1;
    \pgfextractx\tempx{\pgfpointanchor{tmp}{center}}
    \pgfextracty\tempy{\pgfpointanchor{tmp}{center}}
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Compile this code snippet in a working MWE and it will be more valuable. That way interested users can see exactly how to utilize your "wrong doings". :)

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of convenience, I've written these small `\def` and macro that should help to pretty print point coordinates.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\pdfminorversion 7
\pdfobjcompresslevel 3
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1,dec sep={,}}
    \def\pttocm#1{\pgfmathparse{#1 / 19.93333
    }\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}

    \newcommand{\printcoords}[1]{
      \newdimen\posx
      \pgfextractx{\posx}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
      \newdimen\posy
      \pgfextracty{\posy}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
      (\pttocm\posx ; \pttocm\posy )
    }

    \draw [thick,->] (-4.3,0) -- (4.3,0) node[below] {$x$} ;
    \draw [thick,->] (0,-2.3) -- (0,7.2) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw [dotted] (-4.3,-2.3) grid (4.3,7.2) ;
    \draw [name path=h,thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-4,-2)(-3,2)(-2,6)(0,2)
    (2,-2)(3,4)} ;
    \draw (0,0) node [below left] {0} ;
    \draw (1,0) node [below] {1} ;
    \draw (0,1) node [left] {1} ;
    \foreach \i in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
    { \draw[very thick] (\i,0) -- (\i,-0.15) ; }
    \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
    { \draw[very thick] (0,\i) -- (-0.15,\i) ; }
    \foreach \i/\j in { -4/-2, 3/4 }
    { \draw (\i,\j) node[fill,circle, inner sep=1pt] {} ; }
    \draw (-3,-1) node[xshift=-2mm,yshift=1mm] {${C}_h$} ;

    \draw [name path=g,thick,red] plot[domain=-4.3:4.3]
    (\x,{ -(\x-2)*2/3 }) ;
    \draw [dashed,very thick,red] (2,0) -- (2,-2) -- (0,-2) ;
    \draw [name path=eq,red] (-4.3,2) -- (4.3,2) ;
    \path [name intersections ={of = h and eq }] ;
    \coordinate (A) at (intersection-1) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (A) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (A) node[below left] {\printcoords{A}} ;
    \coordinate (B) at (intersection-2) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (B) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (B) node[above right] {\printcoords{B}} ;
    \coordinate (C) at (intersection-3) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (C) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (C) node[above right] {\printcoords{C}} ;
    \path [name intersections ={of = h and g }] ;
    \coordinate (D) at (intersection-1) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (D) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (D) node[above right] {\printcoords{D}} ;
    \coordinate (E) at (intersection-2) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (E) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (E) node [above right] {\printcoords{E}} ;
    \coordinate (F) at (intersection-3) ;
    \draw[red,thick] (F) node[draw,circle] {} ;
    \draw[red] (F) node[above right] {\printcoords{F}} ;
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It even handles multiple intersection points, thanks to the intersection library.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this might answer the question, it is always better to post a full example such that users can test immediately

Answer (score 4):

I had a matrix of points, named say `e1, ..., e6` on the y-coordinate and `S1, ..., S5` along the x-coordinate. My goal was to draw a small square at the coordinates `(ei -| Sj)` only for some given points (like an adjacency matrix).

I was trying to use the previous solutions for extracting x and y component of a point from a list, like

```
\foreach \pt in {(1 ,2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4)} {
    \parsept{\x}{\y}{\pt}
    \fill (S\x |- e\y) +(-1, -1) rectangle +(1, 1);
}
```

Note that in this case **the previous solutions will not work**, because they extract **the raw coordinate** computed by TikZ, so the TeX engine would look for some point named `S28.221344pt` (failing).

So I ended up writing a naive macro for parsing `( x , y )` expressions. The solution may be useful for other readers that **require the coordinates to be parsed literally**:

```
\makeatletter
\def\parsept#1#2#3{%
    \def\nospace##1{\zap@space##1 \@empty}%
    \def\rawparsept(##1,##2){%
        \edef#1{\nospace{##1}}%
        \edef#2{\nospace{##2}}%
    }%
    \expandafter\rawparsept#3%
}
\makeatother
```

The macro strips away all spaces in the argument (so `\parsept{\x}{\y}{( a b, c)}` will yield `\x=ab` and `\y=c`), but I couldn't make `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` working in this context. Credits for removing spaces go to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87510/26355).