# Create named coordinate from extracted x/y parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can not find a way to effectively identify coordinates of the point, if used in the command let in the draw path. My example:

```
  \draw[gray] let \p1=(D), \p2=(intersect), \p3=(C) in (\x1,\y2)
           -- +(-\x1,0) node[left, red]{$f(c)$} -- (\x1,\y2) node[above, red]{$F$}
           -- (\x3,\y2) node[right, red]{$E$};
```

Now I would like to create named coordinate for node with text $F$:

```
  \coordinate (F) at (\x1,\y2);
```

but with error. How I could I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just name the node `... (\x1,\y2) node[...] (F) {$F$}` and then you have access to the node via `(F)`, so you can do something like:

```
\draw (F) circle (5pt);
```

If you really need the x and y coordinates you can use the solution from [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz/33706#33706):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz/33706#33706
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (D) at (2,0);
\coordinate (intersect) at (1,1);

  \draw[gray] let \p1=(D), \p2=(intersect), \p3=(C) in (\x1,\y2)
           -- +(-\x1,0) node[left, red]{$f(c)$} -- (\x1,\y2) node[above, red] (F) {$F$}
           -- (\x3,\y2) node[right, red]  {$E$};

\draw (F) circle (5pt);% can just use the node name

\ExtractCoordinate{F}
node [below] (F) {$(\XCoord,\YCoord)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \ExtractCoordinate{F} ... it is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the orthogonal intersections to avoid `let` operation, hence the `calc` library for such applications.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (C) at (2cm,2cm);
\coordinate (D) at (-2cm,-3cm);
\coordinate (intersect) at (1cm,1cm);

\draw[thick,gray] (D |- intersect) coordinate (F) -- 
+([scale=-1]D|-{{(0,0)}}) node[left, red]{$f(c)$} -- 
(F) node[above, red] {$F$}--
(C|-intersect) node[right, red]  {$E$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jake, the solution of my problem is trivial:

```
  \draw[gray] let \p1=(D), \p2=(intersect), \p3=(C) in (\x1,\y2)
              -- +(-\x1,0) node[left, red]{$f(c)$} 
              -- (\x1,\y2) node[above, red]{$F$} coordinate (F) at (\x1,\y2) 
              -- (\x3,\y2) node[right, red]{$E$};
```