# Removing the spaces between words

Tags: spacing, macros

Is there any way to remove spaces from in between the words in a text? Something like

```
\RemoveSpaces{This is   my    sentence.}
```

which will be converted to

> Thisismysentence.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: As a deterrent against copy and pasting the real text from the resulting searchable PDF file.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\RemoveSpaces#1{\zap@space#1 \@empty}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I didn't believe it, but ... it works!

Answer (score 33):

A different approach, that ensures correct hyphenation and line breaks between words is

```
\newcommand{\RemoveSpaces}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip=1sp
  \xspaceskip=1sp
  #1%
  \endgroup}
```

This reduces the interword space to the minimum possible positive value (that's not visible to the human eye), but still paragraphs will be built as usual.
Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\RemoveSpaces#1{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip1sp
  \xspaceskip1sp
  #1%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\parbox{5cm}{\RaggedRight
\RemoveSpaces{\lipsum[2]}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

a solution with `lualatex` for *all* spaces between words in a paragraph. Kerning and discretionaries are not affected.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel,libertine,luacode,blindtext}
\begin{luacode*}
function rSpace(List)
 for line in node.traverse_id(0,List) do -- go through all lines
   for s in node.traverse_id(10,line.head) do node.remove(line.head,s) end 
 end 
 return List
end
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\blindtext \par
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",rSpace,"rSpace")}
\blindtext \par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can handle macros in the argument, but it will not remove spaces from groups within the argument (as in argument lists within the argument to `\RemoveSpaces`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\RemoveSpaces[1]{\setsepchar{ }\readlist\myarg{#1}\foreachitem\x\in\myarg{\x}}
\begin{document}
\RemoveSpaces{This is   my    sentence.}

\RemoveSpaces{This is   my  \detokenize{\  textit {italic}}  sentence.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that can reach into the groups within the argument.  However, the restriction that goes along with this ability is that the argument must now be expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\RemoveSpaces[1]%
  {\edef\tmp{#1}\setsepchar{ }\readlist\myarg{\tmp}\foreachitem\x\in\myarg{\x}}
\begin{document}
\RemoveSpaces{This is   my    sentence.}

\RemoveSpaces{This is   my  \detokenize{\  textit {italic}}  sentence.}
\end{document}
```

[image]