# Extracting x, y coordinates of an arbitrary point in TiKZ while using yscale and xscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, coordinates

Inspired by [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz), I am trying to use the x coordinate of a point to draw another element.

However, when I use the `yscale` and `xscale` commands, the extracted coordinates do not similarly scale up. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % First picture
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0) ;
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) ;    

  \coordinate (z) at (0.5,0);
  \path (z) node[below] {$z$};
  \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};

  \coordinate (kink) at (\XCoord,\XCoord);
  \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (kink) node[above, red] {$c$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=4,xscale=6] % Second picture
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0) ;
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) ;    

  \coordinate (z) at (0.5,0);
  \path (z) node[below] {$z$};
  \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};

  \coordinate (kink) at (\XCoord,\XCoord);
  \draw[gray] (0,0) -- (kink) node[above, red] {$c$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: First picture with no xscale/yscale]
[image: Second picture with xscale/yscale]

In the first picture, the extracted coordinate works as expected. In the second picture, I try to scale up the entire picture, but the extracted coordinate now extends off of the page. How do I get the extracted coordinate to scale correctly?

Comment: One option is to use `[y=4cm,x=6cm]` instead of `[yscale=4,xscale=6]`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, yes I did forget to include `\coordinate (kink) at (\XCoord,\XCoord);` in the second picture. When I do that, the node extends way off the page. But, as you say, the answers below solve the problem.

Comment: Related: [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380838/extracting-coordinates-of-a-node-and-the-one-node-path-trick) (It seems that some consider an alternative to the one-node-path-method   \path (z) node[below] {$z$};
  \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}; more recommendable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this happens because you're mixing TikZ transformations with PGF commands for extracting the coordinates. One way to fix this is to reset the transformations when using the dimensions extracted using `\pgfgetlastxy`. You can do this by using `\begin{scope}[reset cm]` (or by using `\path [reset cm] coordinate` instead of just `\coordinate`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=4,xscale=6]

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) ;  

\coordinate (z) at (0.5,0);
\path (z) node[below] {$z$};
\pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};

\begin{scope}[reset cm]
    \coordinate (kink) at (\XCoord,\XCoord);
\end{scope}

\draw[gray] (0,0) -- (kink) node[above, red] {$c$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a TikZ way: `\path[reset cm] coordinate (kink) at (\XCoord,\XCoord);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Ah yes, thank you! I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jake Is there a way to transform and store the x and y coordinates separately?