# angled lines of unkown length in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I am trying to create angled lines from a point to specific border. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5, 0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5, -5);
    \coordinate (D) at (1, -4);
    \clip (A) rectangle (C); 
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \foreach \a in {10,30,...,70}{
        \draw (D) -- +(\a:3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I set the length of these lines? 3 is to short. Setting the value to 10 solves the problem. However, resizing A, B and C gives the same problem.
Is it possible to draw the lines until they hit a border? Or can I calculate a length in TikZ? I only know the calculation of points, but here I need a length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0cm, 0cm);
    \coordinate (B) at (5cm, 0cm);
    \coordinate (C) at (5cm, -5cm);
    \coordinate (D) at (1cm, -4cm);

    \newlength\lendiag;
    \pgfmathsetlength{\lendiag}{veclen(\linewidth,\linewidth)};

    \clip (A) rectangle (C); 


    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);

    \foreach \a in {10,30,...,70}{
        \draw (D) -- +(\a:(\lendiag););
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this minimal example, I took `\linewidth` twice which is independend of the given points. This is not optimal, of cause. In my productive solution I use `\textwidth` and `\textheight` to determine the points and to calculate `\lendiag`. So the length is always long enough.

Answer (score 5):

Here a suggestion where you compute the maximum distance between coordinates.

The function `\MaxNodeDistance` has two mandatory arguments. The first argument is the reference point. The second argument can be a list with defined coordinates. The result of the function is the macro `\Distance`.

The command `\gettikxy` is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/5239

To demonstrate the command I change the command `clip` to `draw` and add the angle 45 which is the maximum distance.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand \MaxNodeDistance { m >{ \SplitList { , } } m }
 {
  \def\Distance{0pt}
  \gettikzxy{(#1)}{\xa}{\ya}
  \ProcessList {#2} { \dirk_nodedistance_aux:n }
%  \Distance
 }
\cs_new:Npn  \dirk_nodedistance_aux:n #1
 {
    \gettikzxy{(#1)}{\xb}{\yb}
    \pgfmathparse{max( (veclen(\xa-\xb,\ya-\yb)) ,\Distance }
    \edef\Distance{\pgfmathresult pt}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5, 0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5, -5);
    \coordinate (D) at (1, -4);
    \draw (A) rectangle (C); 
    \MaxNodeDistance{D}{A,B,C} 
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \foreach \a in {10,30,45,50,70,90}{
        \draw (D) -- +(\a:\Distance);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! However, it is much code to get a length. I was wondering, that it is so difficult to calculate this length. I took your proposed `veclen` and create another solution. I post it in this thread.

Answer (score 4):

First solution, instead of 3cm use a larger length, 10cm. Your `clip` rectangle will cut all lines at its border.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5, 0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5, -5);
    \coordinate (D) at (1, -4);
    \clip (A) rectangle (C); 
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \foreach \a in {10,30,...,70}{
        \draw (D) -- +(\a:10);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Second solution: use `intersections` library:

1- Load library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
```

2- Define which paths will be intersected assigning a `name` to them:

```
\draw[name path=border] (A) -- (B) -- (C);

\path[name path=line] (D)--+(\a:10);
```

3- draw the angled line form its origin to intersection point:

```
\draw[name intersections={of=border and line}] (D) -- (intersection-1);
```

With this solution you don't need to use a `clip` path but if you need a bounding box which not considers `(\a:10)` points must use `overlay` option in:

```
\path[name path=line,overlay] (D)--+(\a:10);
```

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5, 0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5, -5);
    \coordinate (D) at (1, -4);
 %   \clip (A) rectangle (C); 
    \draw[name path=border] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \foreach \a in {10,30,...,70}{
        \path[name path=line,overlay] (D)--+(\a:10);
        \draw[name intersections={of=border and line}] (D) -- (intersection-1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both solutions will give you

[image]

Comment: Your second approach needs also a manual set of the length.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yes, it needs. Dirk's code draws lines which don't reach the border, so I thought the problem was `how to reach the border without drawing beyond it`.

Comment: I said, that it should work with different coordinates, so I do not knwo a suitable maximum length.

Comment: @Dirk: In your example you are using a fixed length.

Comment: Yes, but I wrote that this does not solve my problem. I mentioned, that I can set the value to 10, but this does not solve the problem, too.

Comment: Intersecting the lines is an interessting way, but one needs a value (here it is 10) that intersects the border. Usually, this is not given when adjusting A, B, C.

Comment: @Dirk: I used `10` (means 10cm) because it was long enough. I imagin that you have a certain idea about your diagram's final size and can provide a number large enough. If not, just use an exagerated number (`583` was the larger which worked for me). It won't have any effect over your diagram if you use `clip` or use `intersections` to delimit the graphic. Of course it's not so elegant and clever as Marco's solution, but it's easier to remember.

Comment: You are right. However, I do not want to restrict me to a certain number. So I use length like `\textwidth` and `\textheight` in my solution.