# Tikz: Equal sized nodes with different text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am new here to `Tikz` and I need to draw 2 rows of nodes that are identical in size but having different text of different length in it. Sure the upper and lower nodes should have enough room for the longest of the two texts. The upper nodes should be aligned to the lower ones and have the same size.

To be specific, I need to draw the following picture using `Tikz`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a MWE showing some code illustrating your problem. A MWE begins with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem not easy for you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a solution without hard-coded widths; LaTeX does all the calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible TikZ free solution with automatic width calculation and allowing multi-line texts (a TikZ solution is below):

[image]

The command `\EightTexts` has eight mandatory arguments and LaTeX performs all necessary calculations using simple conditional tests on the length of the corresponding strings. The code in the image was produced using

```
\EightTexts{Small}{Medium}{Large}{Larger}{AA}{Even larger}{B}{The largest}

\vskip1cm

\EightTexts{AAAA}{B}{CCCCC}{DD}{EEEEEEEEE}{FFFFF}{GG}{HHHHHHHH}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newlength\mylenai
\newlength\mylenbi
\newlength\mylenMaxi
\newlength\mylenaii
\newlength\mylenbii
\newlength\mylenMaxii
\newlength\mylenaiii
\newlength\mylenbiii
\newlength\mylenMaxiii
\newlength\mylenaiv
\newlength\mylenbiv
\newlength\mylenMaxiv

\newsavebox\myboxi
\newsavebox\myboxii
\newsavebox\myboxiii
\newsavebox\myboxiv
\newsavebox\myboxv
\newsavebox\myboxvi
\newsavebox\myboxvii
\newsavebox\myboxviii

\newcommand\TikZEightTexts[8]{%
% Save the texts in boxes so we can measure their widths. 
\savebox\myboxi{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#1\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#2\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxiii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#3\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxiv{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#4\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxv{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#5\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxvi{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#6\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxvii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#7\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxviii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#8\end{varwidth}}
% Choose maximum width between width of first box and fifth box
% store the maximum in `\mylenMaxi`
\setlength\mylenMaxi{\the\wd\myboxi}%
\setlength\mylenai{\the\wd\myboxi}%
\setlength\mylenbi{\the\wd\myboxv}%
\ifdim\mylenbi>\mylenai\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxi{\mylenbi}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of second box and the 
% width of sixth box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxii`
\setlength\mylenMaxii{\the\wd\myboxii}%
\setlength\mylenaii{\the\wd\myboxii}%
\setlength\mylenbii{\the\wd\myboxvi}%
\ifdim\mylenbii>\mylenaii\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxii{\mylenbii}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of third box and the 
% width of seventh box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxiii`
\setlength\mylenMaxiii{\the\wd\myboxiii}%
\setlength\mylenaiii{\the\wd\myboxiii}%
\setlength\mylenbiii{\the\wd\myboxvii}%
\ifdim\mylenbiii>\mylenaiii\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxiii{\mylenbiii}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of fourth box and the 
% width of eighth box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxiv`
\setlength\mylenMaxiv{\the\wd\myboxiv}%
\setlength\mylenaiv{\the\wd\myboxiv}%
\setlength\mylenbiv{\the\wd\myboxviii}%
\ifdim\mylenbiv>\mylenaiv\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxiv{\mylenbiv}
\fi
\noindent
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxi}{\centering#1}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxii}{\centering#2}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxiii}{\centering#3}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxiv}{\centering#4}}%
\bigskip\par\noindent
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxi}{\centering#5}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxii}{\centering#6}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxiii}{\centering#7}}\hfill
\fbox{\parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\mylenMaxiv}{\centering#8}}\par
}

\begin{document}

\TikZEightTexts{Small}{Medium}{Large}{Larger}{AA}{Even larger}{B}{The 3 lines\\largest solution\\ever}

\vskip1cm

\TikZEightTexts{AAAA \\ AAAAAAAA \\ AAA}{B}{CCCCC}{DD}{EEEEEEE}{FFFFF}{GG \\ GGG }{HH \\ HH}

\end{document}
```

A solution using TikZ has been required in comments; here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength\mylenai
\newlength\mylenbi
\newlength\mylenMaxi
\newlength\mylenaii
\newlength\mylenbii
\newlength\mylenMaxii
\newlength\mylenaiii
\newlength\mylenbiii
\newlength\mylenMaxiii
\newlength\mylenaiv
\newlength\mylenbiv
\newlength\mylenMaxiv

\newsavebox\myboxi
\newsavebox\myboxii
\newsavebox\myboxiii
\newsavebox\myboxiv
\newsavebox\myboxv
\newsavebox\myboxvi
\newsavebox\myboxvii
\newsavebox\myboxviii

\newcommand\TikZEightTexts[8]{%
% Save the texts in boxes so we can measure their widths. 
\savebox\myboxi{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#1\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#2\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxiii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#3\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxiv{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#4\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxv{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#5\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxvi{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#6\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxvii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#7\end{varwidth}}
\savebox\myboxviii{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#8\end{varwidth}}
% Choose maximum width between width of first box and fifth box
% store the maximum in `\mylenMaxi`
\setlength\mylenMaxi{\the\wd\myboxi}%
\setlength\mylenai{\the\wd\myboxi}%
\setlength\mylenbi{\the\wd\myboxv}%
\ifdim\mylenbi>\mylenai\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxi{\mylenbi}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of second box and the 
% width of sixth box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxii`
\setlength\mylenMaxii{\the\wd\myboxii}%
\setlength\mylenaii{\the\wd\myboxii}%
\setlength\mylenbii{\the\wd\myboxvi}%
\ifdim\mylenbii>\mylenaii\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxii{\mylenbii}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of third box and the 
% width of seventh box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxiii`
\setlength\mylenMaxiii{\the\wd\myboxiii}%
\setlength\mylenaiii{\the\wd\myboxiii}%
\setlength\mylenbiii{\the\wd\myboxvii}%
\ifdim\mylenbiii>\mylenaiii\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxiii{\mylenbiii}
\fi
% Choose maximum width between the width of fourth box and the 
% width of eighth box; store the maximum in `\mylenMaxiv`
\setlength\mylenMaxiv{\the\wd\myboxiv}%
\setlength\mylenaiv{\the\wd\myboxiv}%
\setlength\mylenbiv{\the\wd\myboxviii}%
\ifdim\mylenbiv>\mylenaiv\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxiv{\mylenbiv}
\fi
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={
draw,minimum height=1.3cm,align=center}
]
\node[text width=\mylenMaxi] (11) {#1};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxii,right= of 11] (12) {#2};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxiii,right= of 12] (13) {#3};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxiv,right= of 13] (14) {#4};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxi,below=of 11] (21) {#5};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxii,right= of 21] (22) {#6};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxiii,right= of 22] (23) {#7};
\node[text width=\mylenMaxiv,right= of 23] (24) {#8};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\TikZEightTexts{Small}{Medium}{Large}{Larger}{AA}{Even larger}{B}{The 3 lines\\largest solution\\ever}

\vskip1cm

\TikZEightTexts{AAAA \\ AAAAAAAA \\ AAA}{B}{CCCCC}{DD}{EEEEEEE}{FFFFF}{GG \\ GGG }{HH \\ HH}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Medina, but here you have made all boxes of the same size. Besides, in your first solution you don't know the width in advance.

Comment: @Power_Project Ah, I think I know what you want. Please see my updated answer. No need to do anything. LaTeX can do all the measurements for you :)

Comment: Thank you for this great and very helpful solution. Please do not remove it but I need to perform this within `Tikz` because this is part of a larger picture that is written in a `\tikzpicture` environment. I will be thankful if you can add the `tikz` approach.

Comment: @Power_Project TikZ approach added :)

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina. I am impressed by your quick responses and most inspiring codes. I couldn't imagine my self coming to such a helpful site. I at least gave you an up-vote for every comment or solution. But please forgive may shallow knowledge I got lost in your large code full of tests and arguments and I hope if you can provide the simplest solution (in pure `tikz`) for a beginner. Many thanks again

Comment: @Power_Project You're welcome. The code is fairly easy once you know how it works: looking at this bit: `\settowidth\mylenMaxi{#1}%
\settowidth\mylenai{#1}%
\settowidth\mylenbi{#5}%
\ifdim\mylenbi>\mylenai\relax
  \setlength\mylenMaxi{\mylenbi}
\fi` the idea is to compare the widths og the first and fifth strings; initially the max width is set to be the one of the first string and then a conditional test is used; if the width of the fifth string is bigger thatn the one of the first string, the max is updated to be the one of the fifth string.

Comment: @Power_Project Similar procedures are performed to select the maximum width for pair of strings second and sixth, third and seventh, and fourth and eighth. Once the maximum widths have been determined, they are used as the widths for the nodes (in the TikZ approach).

Comment: @Power_Project I added some explanatory comments to the answer.

Comment: Aha.. I got your idea now. Still one last request after-which I can accept your answer. If you try to put, as an argument, a two-line or more string, the width of the box is calculated as if the string is a single line. To get my point, try this:  `\TikZEightTexts{Small}{Medium}{Large}{Larger}{AA}{Even larger}{B}{The 3 lines\\largest solution\\ever !!}` You get a box of width for `"The 3 lines largest solution ever !!"`Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Power_Project Please see my updated answer. Multi-line text can now be handled.

Comment: Thank you so much Gonzalo Medina, this is exactly what I am after. A big ACCEPT is not enough for you. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `tikz` `matrix` which simplifies the placement, and creation of node markers, and then `\draw` the boxes after:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz
\newdimen\XCoordA
\newdimen\XCoordB
\newdimen\YCoordA
\newdimen\YCoordB
\newcommand{\ExtractMinX}[3]{%
    % #1 = csname to hold min x value
    % #2 = coordinate 1
    % #3 = coordinate 2
    \path (#2); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordA}{\YCoordA};%
    \path (#3); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordB}{\YCoordB};%
    \ifdim\XCoordA<\XCoordB
        \edef#1{\XCoordA}%
    \else
        \edef#1{\XCoordB}%
    \fi
}%
\newcommand{\ExtractMaxX}[3]{%
    % #1 = csname to hold max x value
    % #2 = coordinate 1
    % #3 = coordinate 2
    \path (#2); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordA}{\YCoordA};%
    \path (#3); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordB}{\YCoordB};%
    \ifdim\XCoordA>\XCoordB
        \edef#1{\XCoordA}%
    \else
        \edef#1{\XCoordB}%
    \fi
}%

\tikzset{My Matrix Node Style/.style={every node/.style={draw=none, minimum height=5ex, anchor=base, row sep=15.0ex, column sep=5.0em}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetmatrixcolumnsep{2.0em}
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, My Matrix Node Style] {
    Small & Medium & Larger Text & Even Larger Text \\[2.0ex]
    Even larger text & Larger Text & Medium & Small \\
};
% Now draw the boxes based on the min and max x value for each column
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {% for each column
    \ExtractMinX{\MinX}{M-1-\x.south west}{M-2-\x.south west}%
    \ExtractMaxX{\MaxX}{M-1-\x.north east}{M-2-\x.north east}%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,2} {% for each row
        \coordinate (Left Bottom) at (\MinX,\YCoordA |- M-\y-\x.south west);
        \coordinate (Right Top) at   (\MaxX,\YCoordB |- M-\y-\x.north east);
        \draw [red, rounded corners=3pt, thick]
            (Left Bottom) rectangle (Right Top);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple thing needs no `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\mylen

\settowidth\mylen{Even larger text}

\newcommand{\row}[4]{%
\fbox{\makebox[\mylen][c]{\rule[-0.55ex]{0ex}{1.2em}#1}}%
\hfill
\fbox{\makebox[\mylen][c]{\rule[-0.55ex]{0ex}{1.2em}#2}}%
\hfill
\fbox{\makebox[\mylen][c]{\rule[-0.55ex]{0ex}{1.2em}#3}}%
\hfill
\fbox{\makebox[\mylen][c]{\rule[-0.55ex]{0ex}{1.2em}#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\row{Small}{Medium}{Larger text}{Even larger text}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent
\row{Even larger text}{Larger text}{Medium}{Small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kumar, but you have fixed the width of the box at first. What I need is a stretchable box which can accommodate for the longer text.

Answer (score 0):

So, probably you need to use the `\phantom{}` command. Here is a MWE but I am sure you will get the idea:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blk/.style={rounded corners, minimum height=.7cm,draw,align=center},node distance=2cm,line width=1pt]

\node (a) [blk] at (0,0){\phantom{small no 2}\\Small\\ \phantom{small no 2}};
\node (b) [blk,below=of a] {\phantom{Small}\\small no 2\\ \phantom{Small;/}};
\node (c) [blk,right=of a] at (0,0){\phantom{short}\\very long text\\ \phantom{short}};
\node (d) [blk,below=of c] {\phantom{very long text}\\short\\ \phantom{very long text}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The out as you need is:

[image]

Comment: Simplest and smartest!! But I have learned a lot from the above solutions. Thanks @AboAmmar.