# TikZ node as character in text

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I use a modified version of the TikZ-solution in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) to draw rounded rectangles around some text to mark it as a button of a program. It's no problem for single characters, but if I use longer terms (as the buttons are named in my program) I get problems with Overfull \hboxes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\rectangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt, rounded corners=4pt, thick] (char) {\sffamily{#1}};}}

\begin{document}
  A rectangled number \rectangled{1}: No problem normally as it is used as normal charakter and TeX can set it in the right position.

  A button with a longer name is marked using the same command and \rectangled{creates an Overfull \textbackslash hbox} if it is set to the end of a line.
\end{document}
```

The produced output looks like this:
[image: Output of MWE]

Is there a better solution to avoid such Overfull \hboxes than rearrange the sentence until it produces no problem anymore?

Comment: what do you want to happen? Do you want linebreaking within the oval? If so, make two closed ovals, or two half open ovals or.....

Comment: If possible I would like to avoid linebreaking, but I think that would produce odd spaces between words in the  line before... But the idea with two half-opened ovals is good. But I guess an automatic solution would be difficult, right?

Comment: Try to `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Comment: it's probably easy (if you know tikz better than I do) to let linebreaking happen as if the rectangle was not there _if that is what you want_ but that makes more sense if the oval is a "highlight" than if it is a "button" If it is a button then breaking it probably doesn't make sense, but you could set the paragraph \raggedright to void overrunning the margin

Comment: @Astrinus microtype can do a lot of things but it can't adjust the size of an unbreakable box.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But can adjust text surrounding the box, in order to avoid the overfull hbox. I'll give it a chance: I wrote "Try" in front of "use package", since it could not be useful.

Comment: Add `\sloppy` to your document or `sloppypar` to the paragraph.

Comment: @Astrinus microtype is already used in my document (not the MWE of course ;)), but unfortunatly doesn't help at this point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As You said, linebreaking is not optimal, so for the moment, the variant of Steven with the sloppypar is my favourite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `sloppypar` will momentarily allow you to overcome the problem.  This problem arises for any oversized box that wants to be typeset at the end of a line.

The `sloppypar` feature (or `\sloppy` for the whole document) changes TeX's penalties to give more emphasis to avoiding margin overruns, at the expense of grossly wide interword spaces.  There is no "free lunch."

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\rectangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt, rounded corners=4pt, thick] (char) {\sffamily#1};}}

\begin{document}
  A rectangled number \rectangled{1}: No problem normally as it is used as normal charakter and TeX can set it in the right position.

\begin{sloppypar}
  A button with a longer name is marked using the same command and \rectangled{creates an Overfull \textbackslash hbox} if it is set to the end of a line.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was the command I had seen times before, but couldn't remember^^ I suspected a much worse result of word spacing than it looks now, so the option works for my present problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version that allows for line breaks and uses an open rectangle on both parts. `\tikzmark` is used to mark the start and end of the text and the ovals are drawn after the text has been typeset:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- This won't work if the text crosses page boundaries.
- The value of `\RoundedCorner` can not be any larger that the current value of `2.0pt`, otherwise end up with artifacts in the rounded corner.  Perhaps a manually drawn `arc` could be used instead if a larger radius is desired.
- The value of `\InnerSep` can be tweaked to adjust the additional horizontal spacing that is added *before* and *after* the text.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).
- You can uncomment [the `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  to see the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to see page boundaries

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand*{\InnerSep}{1pt}% Only applied to x directions
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[inner sep=0] (#1) {};}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz
\newdimen\XCoordA
\newdimen\YCoordA
\newdimen\XCoordB
\newdimen\YCoordB
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[3]{\path (#3); \pgfgetlastxy{#1}{#2};}%

\newcommand*{\RoundedCorner}{2.0pt}% <-- MUST NOT BE ANY LARGER
\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={rounded corners=\RoundedCorner, thick, blue}}

\newcommand*\rectangled[2][]{%
    \tikzmark{Start Mark}#2\tikzmark{End Mark}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \ExtractCoordinate{\XCoordA}{\YCoordA}{Start Mark}
        \ExtractCoordinate{\XCoordB}{\YCoordB}{End Mark}
        \ifdim\YCoordA=\YCoordB% Starts and ends on same line
            \draw[My Line Style,#1]
                ([shift={(-\InnerSep,-0.3*\baselineskip)}]Start Mark.south east) 
                     rectangle 
                ([shift={(\InnerSep,0.7*\baselineskip)}]End Mark.north west)
               ;
        \else% Starts on a different line
            \coordinate (Right Hand Edge) at (Start Mark -| current page text area.east);
            \coordinate (Left Hand Edge)  at (End Mark -| current page text area.west);
            \draw [My Line Style,#1]% Draw start of oval rectangle 
                   ([yshift=-0.3*\baselineskip]Right Hand Edge) 
                -| ([xshift=-\InnerSep]Start Mark.west)
                |- ([yshift=0.7*\baselineskip]Right Hand Edge)
                ;
            \draw [My Line Style,#1]% Draw end of oval rectangle
                   ([yshift=-0.3*\baselineskip]Left Hand Edge) 
                -| ([xshift=\InnerSep]End Mark.east)
                |- ([yshift=0.7*\baselineskip]Left Hand Edge)
                ;
        \fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  A rectangled number \rectangled{1}, or \rectangled[magenta]{word}: No problem
  normally as it is used as normal character and TeX can set it in the right position.

  A button with a longer name marked using the same command \rectangled[red]{used to 
  create an Overfull \textbackslash hbox} if it was set to the end of a line.

  A button with a even longer name \rectangled[brown]{no longer creates a Overfull 
  \textbackslash hbox when it crosses a line} boundary.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution! Never managed to do this on my own... For other usage than my "buttons" really interesting, but for my momentary usage the answer of Steven fits better.