# Calculate coordinates using components of other coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to calculate a new coordinate in relation to two other cordinates. How can I use the x component of one coordinate and the y component of the other?
Thanks in advance.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (a){a};
    \node at (1,1) (b){b};
    \node at ($ (*xcomponent of a*-1,*ycomponent of b*+1) $)
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: i hoped there was a something like `/getxy(variable){x component} {y component}` but if there is no such command think i will use `\path(a)` and`\pgfgetlastxy{\Xa}{\Ya}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `|-` operation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (a){a};
    \node at (1,1) (b){b};
    \node at ($(a |- b) + (-1,1) $) {c};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Or you may use the `let` operation (same result):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (a){a};
    \node at (1,1) (b){b};
    \path let \p1=(a), \p2=(b) in
    node at (\x1 - 1cm, \y2 + 1cm) {c};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my dokument I tried `|-` and it worked after changenging `a|-b` to `b|-a` but I do not know how and why it works.

Comment: @moku89 With `b|-a`, you get the x coordinate of `b` and the y coordinate of `a`: you get a coordinate vertically (`|`) aligned with `b` and horizontally (`-`) aligned with `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the coordinates via [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz) and then perform the coordainte calculations:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should avoid the `minimal` class as per [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinateX}[2]{\path (#2); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}; \xdef#1{\XCoord}}%
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinateY}[2]{\path (#2); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}; \xdef#1{\YCoord}}%


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (a){a};
    \node at (1,1) (b){b};
    
    \ExtractCoordinateX{\NewX}{a}
    \ExtractCoordinateY{\NewY}{b}
    \coordinate (X) at (\NewX,\NewY);
    
    \node [draw=red, shape=circle] at ($ (X)+ (-1,1) $) {X};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```