# tikz: How can I find the value of `current page.north west`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is there a way to somehow know the exact value of `current page.north west`, etc. in `tikzpicture`?

I'm using `current page.north west` for the placement of the below node, but I'm also curious about its actual coordinates. How would I go about printing it out in the text?

```
\node [color=white,anchor=center] at ($(current page.north west)+(1.4,-1.765)$) {Text for my node};
```

If I try the below, it outputs a literal **current page.north west** as the text instead of the value.

```
\node [color=white,anchor=center] at ($(current page.north west)+(1.4,-1.765)$) {current page.north west};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the motivation for that?

Comment: It should be related to `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.

Comment: The [remember picture] option will compute the location of (current page.north west) relative to the tikzpicture origin (which is what \pgfgetlastxy will report).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/86 has a few different techniques for getting the coordinates of points in TikZ.  As John says, they will be relative to what TikZ considers the origin of the current picture to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to tikz document P.260:

https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

The `current page` is a predefined node in `tikz`. This node can be used to access the current page. It is a node of shape rectangle whose south west anchor is the lower left corner of the page and whose north east anchor is the upper right corner of the page.  You can reference it as if it were defined in some remembered picture other than the current one. Thus, by giving the `remember picture` and the `overlay` options to a picture, you can position nodes absolutely on a page.

To illustrate this, I used the following code to pointing out some locations of the current page. I extract the coordinates of these locations using the command `\pgfgetlastxy{\marcox}{\marcoy}`. And type out the coordinates use `\marcox` and `\marcoy`. The extracted coordinate results depend on where you insert your `tikzpicture` environment. In this example, the `tikzpicture` environment is inserted right after the `text`: "text before tikz". So `tikz` will treat the bottom left corner of typing box after the letter `z` as the origin. The extracted coordinate at this origin location will be (0pt,0pt). And the rest of extracted coordinates will according to this origin location. If the node is located at the left side of the origin, the x coordinate will be negative. If the node is located below the origin, the y coordinate will be negative.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\Large
text before tikz\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)]

\draw [line width=2pt,purple,->] (3,26) -- (current page.north west);\pgfgetlastxy{\NWx}{\NWy}
\node at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west] {node (current page.north west)};
\node at (3,26) [line width=2pt,shape=rectangle,draw=purple,anchor=north west] {\NWx,\NWy};

\draw [line width=2pt,red,->] (18,10) -- (current page.east);\pgfgetlastxy{\eastx}{\easty}
\node at (current page.east) [anchor=south east] {node (current page.east)};
\node at (18,10) [line width=2pt,shape=rectangle,draw=red,anchor=north east] {\eastx,\easty};

\draw [line width=2pt,blue,->] (3,10) -- (current page.west);\pgfgetlastxy{\westx}{\westy}
\node at (current page.west) [anchor=south west] {node (current page.west)};
\node at (3,10) [line width=2pt,shape=rectangle,draw=blue,anchor=north west] {\westx,\westy};

\draw [line width=2pt,green,->] (3,5) -- (current page.south west);\pgfgetlastxy{\SWx}{\SWy}
\node at (current page.south west) [anchor=south west] {node (current page.south west)};
\node at (3,5) [line width=2pt,shape=rectangle,draw=green,anchor=south west] {\SWx,\SWy};

\draw [line width=2pt,orange,<-] (235.30008pt,656.56944pt) -- (8,21);\pgfgetlastxy{\originx}{\originy}
\node at (8,21) [line width=2pt,shape=rectangle,draw=orange,anchor=north] {\originx,\originy};
\end{tikzpicture} text after tikz

\end{document}
```

The output PDF illustrate the results better than what I write here.

[image]