# TikZ strange default anchor behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, anchor

I am using TeX Live 2023 downloaded from the site on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04. Using XeTeX to generate PDF documents.

`xetex -v` is `XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023)`.

As part of planning to work on custom page size, utilize full paper width and intension to use TikZ package, I started with simple LaTeX document. Contrary to documented behavior of anchor (origin) for "tikzpicture" being south-west (bottom left), I am getting a different behavior. I have provided 4 `.tex` files I tried on my system, all with minor differences.

In each of the following, I am trying to print two rectangular boxes with some text below it within `tikzpicture` environment. I would like to use full page hence margin is set to 0 and one of the box is expected to start at position (0,0) ie. from the edges of a paper. I am also using `\begin{scope} ... \end{scope}` to use relative coordinates within the `tikzpicture` environment.

For each file, I run `xetex` command thrice to ensure that "remember picture" and "overlay" works as expected.

- (1) `tikz-default-notworking.tex`: This file contains +ve Y coordinate. Output is not as expected, 1st box is partially visible and 2nd box is not visible at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry} % Adjust size as needed
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers and headers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0cm, 0cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,1cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 1.5cm) {Below First rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5cm, 5cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,2cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 3cm) {Below Second rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- (2) `tikz-explicit-yscale.tex`: Similar to (1) `tikz-default-notworking.tex` but this file use "yscale=-1" in `tikzpicture`. Now, boxes are printed assuming anchor as north-west, not south-west. Moreover, it starts from some margin on left and top.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry} % Adjust size as needed
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers and headers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, yscale=-1]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0cm, 0cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,1cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 1.5cm) {Below First rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, yscale=-1]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5cm, 5cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,2cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 3cm) {Below Second rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- (3) `tikz-default-as-north-west.tex`: Similar to  (1) `tikz-default-notworking.tex` but this file use -ve Y coordinate instead of "yscale=-1". This file produces exactly same as output like "yscale=-1" ie. anchor is treated as north-west and (0,0) starts with some margin on left and top.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry} % Adjust size as needed
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers and headers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0cm, 0cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,-1cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, -1.5cm) {Below First rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5cm, -5cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,-2cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, -3cm) {Below Second rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- (4) `tikz-explicit-south-west.tex`: This file explicitly sets `tikzpicture` anchor to south-west and maintains same coordinates as (1) `tikz-default-notworking.tex`. This time, output is correctly produced as expected, boxes are rendered at the bottom left. Moreover, this time, (0,0) starts with bottom-left corner of a page, without any margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry} % Adjust size as needed
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbers and headers
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.south west)}]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0cm, 0cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,1cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 1.5cm) {Below First rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.south west)}]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5cm, 5cm)}] % Positioned partway down the page
    % Draw a rectangle
    \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4cm,2cm); % Moves downward within the scope
    % Place text below the rectangle
    \node at (2cm, 3cm) {Below Second rectangle}; % Further down (more negative Y)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I fail to understand why default anchor behavior is different on my system, and why (0,0) leaves a margin in case default anchor is "north-west" but works as expected when "anchor = south-west" is explicitly set. If stack exchange permits uploading `.tex` and `.pdf` files, I will upload those as well.

Comment: The way you think where is point (0,0) was not the correct way `tikz` will think. `tikz` will always treat the bottom left corner of your current input location as (0,0). Any shifts you set will be followed as: positive x to the right and positive y to top, vice versa. Take a look this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642203/267375

Comment: Also, I think you forget there will be indent at beginning of the paragraph by default if paragraph was not directly after a section heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example to explain why there are some gaps even the margin was already set to `0`. By default, there will be paragraph indent (horizontally) and topskip (vertical) space before the first letter been type out on a page. So, the (0,0) was not on the page north west corner. To make (0,0) on the page north west corner, you need manually shift to that point (e.g. `shift={(-\parindent, -\topskip)}` when `yscale=-1` or just simply use the predefined the page node `shift={(current page.north west)}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, yscale=-1]
\draw [<-] (0,0) -- (1cm,1cm) node [anchor=north west,,inner sep=0pt] {This is the location of (0,0) outside the scope};
\begin{scope}[shift={(-\parindent, -\topskip)}] 
\draw [<-] (0,0) -- (1.5cm,2cm) node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] {This is the location of (0,0) inside the scope}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}text start here...
\end{document}
```

[image]