# How to "create" millimeter paper using pfgplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I want to replicate some graphs that I drew by hand on millimeter paper. Here is a picture:

[image]

My current code is as follows (I didn't worry about the data yet):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines = middle,
                xlabel = t\lbrack\si{\second}\rbrack, 
                ylabel = x\lbrack\si{\metre}\rbrack, 
                x label style = {anchor = north west, font = \scriptsize},
                y label style = {anchor = north east, font = \scriptsize, shift={(0,0.5cm)}},
                xtick = {0,10,...,20},
                minor xtick = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
                ytick = {0,10,...,20},
                minor ytick = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
                tick style = {line width = 0.3pt},
                ticklabel style = {font = \tiny, fill = white},
                axis line style = {-latex},
                grid = both,
                ymin = 0, 
                ymax = 21, 
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = 21,
                ]
                \addplot[
                only marks,
                mark size = 2,
                black, 
                error bars/.cd, 
                y dir = both, 
                x dir = both, 
                y explicit, 
                x explicit
                ]
                %table[x= temp, y = temp, x error = temp, y error = temo]
                %{\datafile};
                coordinates {(6.4,7.2) +-(1,0.5)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Note that I used dummy values, coordinates, sc and variables; they aren't important right now).

By setting the major and minor grid style I was able to get thick lines on my labeled coordinates and thin lines in between:

```
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {line width = 0.1pt}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {line width = 0.4pt}}
```

But this is where I get stuck. There are several things that I'm not able to do by going this route:

1. I need major grid lines every centimeter, independent of the label.
2. On millimeter paper there are 3 grids; besides the major one with 1cm spacing and the minor one with 1mm spacing, there is a third one every 5mm (with a thickness somewhere between the 2 grids). Using pgfplots I am only able to edit the major and minor grid styles, but I can't seem to find a way to add further grids to a certain graph.
3. Display the plot in "landscape mode" so that it takes up the whole page, as shown in the picture.

I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me out with those issues.

Thanks!

Comment: @those that are eager to close: Is this really a duplicate? It is nontrivial to use the tikz answer for pgfplots.

Comment: I neither consider this as a duplicate, since using the pgfplots environment also directly allows to draw the functions shown in the image, which would require significant work to do in pure tikz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following example works for me so far

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15002/100384
\newcommand*{\getlength}[2]{%
   % Convert to `cm` and round to two fractional digits:
   \pgfmathsetmacro#1{round(0.0351459804*#2)}%
}

\rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % a factor for measures, since pfplots produces slightly bigger images than defined
        %   in width/height. This can be used to adjust that problem manually
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{0.9}

        % we will need some length in `cm`, without units, and rounded
        \getlength{\yMax}{\factor*\textwidth}
        \getlength{\xMax}{\factor*\textheight}

        \begin{axis}[
            set layers,
            width=\factor\textheight, height=\factor\textwidth,
            x=1cm, y=1cm,
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {t\lbrack\si{\second}\rbrack}, 
            ylabel = {x\lbrack\si{\metre}\rbrack}, 
            x label style = {anchor = north west, font = \scriptsize},
            y label style = {anchor = north east, font = \scriptsize, shift={(0,0.5cm)}},
            xtick={0,1,...,\xMax},
            ytick={0,1,...,\yMax},
            minor xtick={0,0.1,0.2,...,\xMax},
            minor ytick={0,0.1,0.2,...,\yMax},
            tick style = {line width = 0.6pt, black!40!white},
            minor tick style = {line width = 0.3pt, black!40!white},
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny, fill=white},
            axis line style = {-latex},
            grid = both,
            minor grid style={line width=0.3pt, black!40!white},
            grid style={line width=0.6pt, black!40!white},
            ymin=0, ymax=\yMax,
            xmin=0, xmax=\xMax,
            ]
            \addplot[only marks] coordinates {(6.4,7.2) +-(1,0.5)};

            % now manually draw the 0.5cm grid on the grid layer
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
                \draw[line width=0.45pt, step=0.5cm, black!40!white] (axis cs: 0, 0) grid (axis cs: \xMax, \yMax);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Notes:

- Do not use any `scale`, `rotate` or similar in the `tikzpicture` or `axis` environment. It will ruin everything. I tried. The **rotatebox** works fine, however.
- To get the **dimensions** correct, you can force pgfplots to use a system of normal vectors of *1cm* by setting them manually `x=1cm, y=1cm`
- The **third grid** needs to be drawn manually. This is not as nice, but works anyway.
- I tried to make it use as much space as exists, however you need a **reduction** `\factor`, since somehow images end up being larger and get shifted on page in the final document. You probably can get away with slightly larger values than 0.9, but you will need to adjust this manually.
- The result in this case is still a very small image. I wold suggest you to use the [`geometry` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to shrink the **margins** and thus reduce the **whitespace** around your image.
- Seeing your example I assume you are familiar enough to adjust line width, font size, colours yourself.
- I removed some irrelevant elements from your example, to shorten stuff a bit.

And this is how the results looked for me (without page margins):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a pretty neat solution! Using variables for the x and y max works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Add the following lines to the options of `axis`

```
axis background/.style={postaction={path picture={
  \draw[line width=.1pt,draw=black!30]
     (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=1]
     (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
  \draw[line width=.1pt,draw=red!50]
     (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=5]
     (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
  \draw[line width=.2pt,draw=red!50]
     (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=10]
     (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
}}},
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis background/.style={postaction={path picture={
                \draw[line width=.1pt,draw=black!30]
                   (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=1]
                   (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                \draw[line width=.1pt,draw=red!50]
                   (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=5]
                   (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                \draw[line width=.2pt,draw=red!50]
                   (axis cs:0,0) grid[step=10]
                   (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                }}},
                axis lines = middle,
                xlabel = t\lbrack\si{\second}\rbrack, 
                ylabel = x\lbrack\si{\metre}\rbrack, 
                x label style = {anchor = north west, font = \scriptsize},
                y label style = {anchor = north east, font = \scriptsize, shift={(0,0.5cm)}},
                xtick = {0,10,...,20},
                minor xtick = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
                ytick = {0,10,...,20},
                minor ytick = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
                tick style = {line width = 0.3pt},
                ticklabel style = {font = \tiny, fill = white},
                axis line style = {-latex},
%                grid = both,
                ymin = 0, 
                ymax = 21, 
                xmin = 0, 
                xmax = 21,
                ]
                \addplot[
                only marks,
                mark size = 2,
                black, 
                error bars/.cd, 
                y dir = both, 
                x dir = both, 
                y explicit, 
                x explicit
                ]
                %table[x= temp, y = temp, x error = temp, y error = temo]
                %{\datafile};
                coordinates {(6.4,7.2) +-(1,0.5)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a nice workaround. I think I'll end up combining both answers to get the result I want.