# Getting the length printed as a length in pt

Tags: lengths

in [Getting length as number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/getting-length-as-number?) I've seen a way to find out the length of `\textwidth`.

However, when instead using for example `\getlength{hey}` I receive an error. That occurred when using the code of all possible answers.

I'd actually like to go even further and obtain the length of something like `| {\footnotesize hey}`

[image: this is an image]

Did I miss something unusually simple or is it just a standard beginner Latex problem?

UPDATE: I'd like to obtain the lengths in point as a return. Or any other small metric like `sp`. So say the length of `| {\footnotesize hey}` was equivalent to `X pt` I'd like to see `X pt` returned in the documents' PDF.

UPDATE2:
Here is an example code of what I would like to use the received length for in this specific case; sorry for the inconvenience so far! Hope this clears up things.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, isbn=true, url=true, doi=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}

\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ R{107pt} | L{278pt} | }

Something
    & Something else \\
    & Something else \\
    & \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l L{\widthof{| some other text}} | }
            Some & thing & {| some text} \\
            Some & thing & {| some other text} \\
      \end{tabular} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is what I'd like to receive:
[image]

Comment: You want `\newlength{\mylength}` in the preamble and then `\settowidth{\mylength}{hey}\getlength{\mylength}` in your document.

Comment: latex has a standard command `\settowidth`  which appears to be what you are looking for,

Comment: Hey thank you both! As far as I have seen and now also tried, this approach only works if I would want to set the length of a function variable to that length of `| {\footnotesize hey}`. I added an update to clarify :)
Edit: for the purpose of what you meant (I guess) I'm currently using the package `calc` and command `\widthof`.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear but you can save the length from `\settolength` in a length command and then use it anywhere a length can be used. Or as you say there is `\widthof` from calc (which is essentially the same thing, but hiding the internal length)

Comment: `\newlength\zzz  \settolength\zzz{| {\footnotesize hey}}  the length is \the\zzz`

Comment: Why do you want this? (it should be fairly rare to need this in latex)

Comment: please also update your title, your UPDATE edit makes it clear you want the _length_ not a _number_

Comment: @Tork for that use you don't need to "get the length in pt" or any other unit. If for example you want a column to be half of the current linewidth you can use `0.5\linewidth`  you don't need to access `\the\linewidth` which will show the value in pt as a string of characters .

Comment: @Tork that sounds massively over complicated it is almost never necessary to measure things to lay out a table, the whole point of the tabular mechanism is that the columns align without the user needing to measure things. but with no example code impossible to say really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an example code, sorry! Deleting my comments as now everything relevant should be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are looking for `\settowidth`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength\zzz
\begin{document}

[hey]

\settowidth\zzz{hey}

[\hspace{\zzz}] (\the\zzz)

\bigskip

[| {\footnotesize hey}]

\settowidth\zzz{| {\footnotesize hey}}

[\hspace{\zzz}] (\the\zzz)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that what I needed! The package apparently sets another font which I guess changes the length of `{\footnotesize hey}` relative to another font? Any work around for this happening? (I've just always been using the standard font until now)

Comment: @Tork really it is impossible to guess your issue if you continue to supply no example code. If you want to ask about font sizes, ask a new question with a new title and a new complete example document that shows the issue.