# Using `\pgfgetlastxy`

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33706) to extract the coordinates of a point without the *pt*. But why is the following not working? The first `\JustNumber` works as exected, but the second not, although `\show\X` gives `> \X=macro:->0.0pt.`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\JustNumber#1pt{#1}
\begin{document}
    \JustNumber0.0pt.
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\X}{\Y}
        \show\X
        \xdef\X{\expandafter\JustNumber\X}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why do I want this? I want to fill the rectangle between two points with a dotted grid. Because patterns seem to cause various problems when it comes to precise positioning, I thought of extracting the coordinates (without the `pt`) and feeding them into a `\foreach`.

Comment: You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\ValueWithoutUnit}{\ValueInPt}` to achieve this. You can also convert into cm in one go: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\ValueWithoutUnit}{\ValueInPt / 1cm}`

Comment: Also, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15001/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is:

With your definition of `\JustNumber` the argument delimiter `pt` is tokenized while reading from the .tex-input-file.
Hereby you get two explicit character tokens of category 11(letter), i.e., <kbd>p<sub>11</sub></kbd><kbd>t<sub>11</sub></kbd>.
But character tokens delivered via `\pgfgetlastxy` seem to come from `\the` which in turn delivers explicit character tokens of category 12(other), i.e., <kbd>p<sub>12</sub></kbd><kbd>t<sub>12</sub></kbd>. (Exception: spaces delivered by `\the` are of category 10(space).)
Thus TeX does not find a matching delimiter.

With your definition ensure that the explicit character tokens forming the delimiter of the argument are of category 12(other):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% \string delivers explicit character tokens with the same catcode-régime
% as \the, so let's stringify the delimiter:
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\JustNumber{%
  \edef\JustNumber{##1\string p\string t}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\JustNumber\JustNumber{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\X}{\Y}
        \show\X
        \xdef\X{\expandafter\JustNumber\X}
        \show\X
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15001/47927 solves my aims better, this answer explains well while my attempt failed.